# golang, revel, How to parse post json?

Tags: php, json, curl, go, revel

I'm rather new in golang, but I'm trying hard..

I'm trying to send json by post request to the revel controller, and parse it on the revel side.

But while getting the result I cannot Unmarshal it... I'm sending an array

```
json_encode(array("one","two","three"))
```

But I can't find the correct way to work with such a data. I'm not sure do I need to make json before sending it or not..

```
func (c KpiCtrl) GetData() revel.Result {
    content, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(c.Request.Body)
    ...
    return c.RenderJson(content)
    }
```

returns

```
"WyJvbmUiLCJ0d28iLCJ0aHJlZSJd"
```

I tried to use json.Unmarshal but it returns errors.. What is the best practice to work with post data sent by curl to revel controller?

Comment: First: check and handle your errors. Second: what is the code you used with json.Unmarshal?

Comment: What does `log.Printf("%q", content)` show? The only thing that encodes to JSON as base64 string is `[]byte`. Did you forget to decode it first?

Comment: I tryied to use json.Unmarshal([]byte(c.Request.Body), &myStruct) , but it said that go can not convert ..io.Reader to []byte....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use standart [json](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json) Decoder:

```
   var content []string
   err := json.NewDecoder(c.Request.Body).Decode(&content)
   if err != nil {
       log.Fatal("JSON decode error: ", err)
   }
   defer c.Request.Body.Close()
   fmt.Println(content)
```

Comment: Tested your answer, works like a charm. Thank you, guru Gopher =).